# Forward Bluetooth socket to serial port

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, serial-port, raspberry-pi, bluez

I've been trying to figure out how to turn my Raspberry Pi into a USB to Bluetooth serial adapter. I want to be able to send data over Bluetooth to the Pi which has a USB thermal printer registered at /dev/usb/lp0.

Using only standard command line apps such as `hciconfig`, `hcitool`, `rfcomm`, and `sdptool` I have been able to see the Pi as visible, and pair to it from an Android tablet using a Bluetooth SPP app on the Store. However, the tablet disconnects immediately, and no data is sent. `rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0 1` also waits for a connection forever.

I think I'm able to achieve what I need without custom code, using solely standard command line apps, but I'm not entirely sure. `socat` will likely be of use to finally connect the sockets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figures that I'd get it right after posting. To anyone else looking to do something similar:

1. Pair with `bluez-simple-agent`
2. Create your serial port channel with `sdptool add --channel=x sp`
3. Listen for a connection on that channel with `sudo rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0 x`
4. Cross the streams with `socat /dev/rfcomm0 /dev/usb/lp0`

Beautiful. It's all so simple now.